# fog shader not working in android platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, game-engine

My fog Shader works fine on the Windows platform but it stopped when I switch to Android platform.

this is a screenshot of scene in windows platform , on android it will be gone
[image]

it's my shader:

```
Shader "Custom/VerticalFogIntersection"
{
    Properties
    {
       _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, .5)
       _IntersectionThresholdMax("Intersection Threshold Max", float) = 1
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"  }

        Pass
        {
           Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
           ZWrite Off
           CGPROGRAM
           #pragma vertex vert
           #pragma fragment frag
           #pragma multi_compile_fog
           #include "UnityCG.cginc"

           struct appdata
           {
               float4 vertex : POSITION;
           };

           struct v2f
           {
               float4 scrPos : TEXCOORD0;
               UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
               float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
           };

           sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;
           float4 _Color;
           float4 _IntersectionColor;
           float _IntersectionThresholdMax;

           v2f vert(appdata v)
           {
               v2f o;
               o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
               o.scrPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
               UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
               return o;   
           }


            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_TARGET
            {
               float depth = LinearEyeDepth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.scrPos)));
               float diff = saturate(_IntersectionThresholdMax * (depth - i.scrPos.w));

               fixed4 col = lerp(fixed4(_Color.rgb, 0.0), _Color, diff * diff * diff * (diff * (6 * diff - 15) + 10));

               UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
               return col;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

- Auto Graphics API : **unchecked**.
- Unity version: **2019.3.4f**.

there is not any error or log.

I also tested builded **APK** on physical android device.

Comment: Android LogCat out?

Comment: A platform specific shader crash would show up in console after the build anyway (or do you mean its gone in Editor with Android Plarform as well?), and your mesh (I assume it's some sort of plane in the scene?) would appear pink. So the shader is fine IMO, I would look into its input: are you properly generating that _CameraDepthTexture ? You could remote frame debug on your device (or Editor if applicable) and check that out, remove all the fluff from your scene and see if it's rendered properly, and with the right content.